# get output from shell_exec command as command runs

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, bash

I am coding a PHP-scripted web page that is intended to accept the filename of a JFFS2 image which was previously uploaded to the server. The script is to then re-flash a partition on the server with the image, and output the results. I had been using this:

```
$tmp = shell_exec("update_flash -v " . $filename . " 4 2>&1");
echo '<h3>' . $tmp . '</h3>';

echo verifyResults($tmp);
```

(The verifyResults function will return some HTML that indicates to the user whether the update command completed successfully. I.e., in the case that the update completes successfully, display a button to restart the device, etc.)

The problem with this is that the update command takes several minutes to complete, and the PHP script blocks until the shell command is complete before it returns any of the output. This typically means that the update command will continue running, while the user will see an HTTP 504 error (at worst) or wait for the page to load for several minutes.

I was thinking about doing something like this instead:

```
shell_exec("rm /tmp/output.txt");
shell_exec("update_flash -v " . $filename . " 4 2>&1 >> /tmp/output.txt &");
echo '<div id="output"></div>';
echo '<div id="results"></div>';
```

This would theoretically put the command in the background and append all output to /tmp/output.txt.

And then, in a Javascript function, I would periodically request getOutput.php, which would simply print the contents of /tmp/output.txt and stick it into the "output" div. Once the command is completely done, another Javascript function would process the output and display a result in the "results" div.

But the problem I see here is that getOutput.php will eventually become inaccessible during the process of updating the device's flash memory, because it's on the partition to which is targeted for an update. So that could leave me in the same position as before, albeit without the 504 or a seemingly eternally-loading page.

I could move getOutput.php to another partition in the device, but then I think I would still have to do some funky stuff with the webserver configuration to be able to access it there (a symlink to it from the webroot would, like any other file, eventually be overwritten during the re-flash).

Is there any other way of displaying the output of the command as it runs, or should I just make do with the solution I have?

**Edit 1:** I'm currently testing some solutions. I'll update my question with results later.

**Edit 2:** It seems that the filesystem does not get overwritten as I had originally thought. Instead, the system seems to mount the existing filesystem in read-only mode, so I can still access getOutput.php even after the filesystem is re-flashed.

The second solution I described in my question does seem to work in addition with using popen (as mentioned in an answer below) instead of shell_exec. The page loads, and via Ajax I can display the contents of output.txt.

<del>**However**, it seems that output.txt does not reflect the output from the re-flash command in real time-- it seems to display nothing until the update command returns from execution. I will need to do further testing to see what's going on here.</del>

**Edit 3:** Never mind, it looks like the file *is* current as I access it. I was just hitting a delay while the kernel did some JFFS2-related tasks triggered by my use of the partition on which the source JFFS2 image is stored. I don't know why, but this apparently causes all PHP scripts to block until it's done.

To work around that, I'm going to put the update command invocation in a separate script and request it via Ajax-- that way, the user will at least receive some prepackaged feedback while technically still waiting on the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the popen: http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

Comment: popen does seem to prevent PHP from blocking as desired, but somehow my command isn't instantly updating my output file-- see edit 2 of my question for details.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting scenario.

My first thought was to do something regarding proc_* and $_SESSION, but I'm not sure if that will work or not. Give it a try, but if not...

If you're worried about the file being flashed during the process, you could always instantiate a mysql database in the secondary process and write to that.  The database can exist on another partition, and you can address it by local ip and the system will take care of the routing.

**Edit**

When I mentioned proc_* with sessions, I meant something similar to [this](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#IYBiINXRm2E/trunk/thomas/siege.php&q=lang%3aphp&l=50) where $descriptorspec would become:

```
$_SESSION = array(
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
);
```

However I kind of doubt that will work.  The process will end up writing to the $_SESSION in memory which no longer exists once the first script is killed.

**Edit 2**

ACTUALLY, on that note, you could install [memcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php) and have your secondary process write directly to memory, which can then be re-read by your web-interfaced process.

Comment: It's a lightweight embedded Linux system, so I don't think I could afford the storage space for a mysql implementation, even if I had a binary :(

Answer (score 1):

If you wipe the DocRoot there is no resource/script that can respond to requests from the user during this time. Therefore you have to send updates to the user in the same request that does the wipe. This requires you to start the shell process and immediately return to PHP. This can be accomplished with `pcntl_fork()` and `pcntl_exec()`. Your PHP script should now continuously send the output of the shell script to the client. If the shell script appends to a file in /tmp, you could `fpassthru()` that file and clear it until the shell script ends.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your ***However***:

My guess is you are trying to use the file as a stream.  I haven't done any production tests, but I believe that the file will only be written back to disk on fclose().

If you are writing to the file continually in script #2, those writes are actually going directly into memory until the file is closed.

Again - I cannot verify this, but if you want to test it, try re-opening and closing the file for every write.  This will confirm or deny my theory and you can modify your approach accordingly.

Comment: The second script just reads the file and outputs its contents; I'm not doing any writes. The file is written to by the command started in script #1: ("update_flash -v " . $filename . " 4 2>&1 >> /tmp/output.txt &").

Comment: Oh yes - sorry. I had it in my head that you were using two PHP scripts for some reason.

Is it possible that there are some conflict with file locks?

Comment: Hm, that could indeed be the case. I checked using cat, which may not behave the same way as PHP's fopen.